# Yahoo Financials Error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I am trying to load in a list of symbols from CSV and then pull historical stock information from YahooFinancials. The program runs until the last component where I get: `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.
I really appreciate any help. This is my fisrt post, so if more info is needed please let me know.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import datetime

#import csv list of symbols
stocksmini = pd.read_csv('watchlistmini.csv')
stocksmini
symbollist = stocksmini['Symbol'].tolist()
symbollist

#symbollist has this format:
['BASWW', 'BBLC', 'EMGE', 'VBVT']

#pull stock info
test = symbollist

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(test)

data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data (start_date='2020-01-01',
                                                   end_date='2020-04-26',
                                                   time_interval='daily')

test2 = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a]['prices']} for a in test
})

test2
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Error (Note: error referencing line starting with a: {x...)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Where is stocksmini defined ?

Comment: Added code above(re:stocksmini). Thanks for calling this out.

Comment: Could you post the first few items of `symbollist`?

Comment: sure. I added this above. thanks.

Comment: Try changing this line - `symbollist = stocksmini['Symbol']` to `symbollist = stocksmini['Symbol'].tolist()`

Comment: Thanks, tried this but still getting same error starting with line a: {x... I think the issue may be in formatting the json to the DataFrame. The code works (returns json for data=...). The error results when I run the last couple lines.

Comment: Just tested your symbol set. It seems the reason for the error is that the symbol `BASWW` has no data and only `None`. If you remove that symbol, it should work fine.